# How to launch Airplane Setting page in Win10?

Tags: c#, window, windows-10

I want to use C# to launch Airplane mode setting page to let user can check current status about internet.

Is there any way can I do that?

Thanks for your help:)

[image: sample image]

Comment: Please be specific. Which type of app you want to create, Windows Store app, Windows Desktop app, or Console Application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within C# you can do it with the following piece of code:

```
Process.Start("ms-settings:network-airplanemode");
```

The "Immersive Control Panel" application is registered with the `ms-settings` protocol.

[HERE](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-open-various-settings-pages-directly-in-windows-10/) is a list of possible pages you can use with the `ms-settings` protocol.